# FileNotFoundError: Op type not registered 'RegexSplitWithOffsets' while loading Keras model

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to load a Keras model on aws server with the following command

```py
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model(model_path, custom_objects={'KerasLayer': hub.KerasLayer})
```

but its giving an error

```py
FileNotFoundError: Op type not registered 'RegexSplitWithOffsets' in binary running on ip-10-0-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.internal. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
 You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the `experimental_io_device` option in `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'.
```

The exact same code was working the other day but this time it's giving an error. I double-checked if the model file is still there on the specified path. Also, the file is not modified so there is no doubt of the file being corrupt or anything.

I guess the error has to do something with aws, but I don't how to resolve it. I tried finding any solution on the web but it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

importing `tensorflow_text` resolve this issue

Comment: This helped so much, thank you! The error message was super cryptic.